# Memory usage of child process in C

Tags: c, linux, memory, fork

I read the [article](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-and-most-accurate-way-to-measure-the-memory-used-by-a-program-in-a-programming-contest-environment) about memory usage calculating in C, and have problem.

I write simple testing program, which could be working more than one second and use more than 1 KB memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int a;
int f[1000000];
sleep(1);
 scanf("%d",&a);
 printf("%d %d\n",a/10,a%10);

return 0;
}
```

Then I compile this to some `main.exe` and do in check program operations from article

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) 
{
    struct rlimit rlim;
    rlim.rlim_cur = rlim.rlim_max = TIME_LIMIT;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &rlim);
    execv("./main.exe",NULL);
}
else 
{
        struct rusage resource_usage;
        // set arbitrary lower limit value of memory used
        int memory_used = 128;
        pid_t pid2;

        do {
            memory_used = max(memory_used, get_memory_usage(pid));
            if ((memory_used > memory_limit)
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);

           // wait for the child process to change state
            pid2 = wait4(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED, &resource_usage);
        } while (pid2 == 0);
}
```

And function `get_memory_usage()` from article

```
int get_memory_usage(pid_t pid) {
    int fd, data, stack;
    char buf[4096], status_child[NAME_MAX];
    char *vm;

    sprintf(status_child, "/proc/%d/status", pid);
    if ((fd = open(status_child, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        return -1;

    read(fd, buf, 4095);
    buf[4095] = '\0';
    close(fd);

    data = stack = 0;

    vm = strstr(buf, "VmData:");
    if (vm) {
        sscanf(vm, "%*s %d", &data);
    }
    vm = strstr(buf, "VmStk:");
    if (vm) {
        sscanf(vm, "%*s %d", &stack);
    }

    return data + stack;    
}
```

But the problem in string, where `pid2 = wait4(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED, &resource_usage);`. `while` make only one iteration and wait for process ends. But I need to calculate memory, and `rusage resource_usage` don't give me this info. How can I make than `while` works while the child process is running and stops where he stops.
There are more problems with status of child process when he ZOMBIE. It doesn't give a memory. I need catch it too. Because if for my `main.exe` I use this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int a;
   int f[1000000];
   sleep(1);
   scanf("%d",&a);
   printf("%d %d\n",a/10,a%10);
   return 0;
}
```

When I do some output from `get_memory_usage` in infinite `while`, it shows me all `/proc/[pid]/status` output. And I see, that child process was

```
Name:   check.exe
State:  R (running)
```

and after that it will

```
Name:   main.exe
State:  Z (zombie)
```

That means the `proc` can't catch information where main.exe is running.

Comment: wait4() <which is obsolete and replaced by waitpid()>  returns:  -1 meaning some failure occurred, 0 meaning no state change occurred, otherwise, returns pid of child.   Suggest checking for (-1 <error> or pid of child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) man page, your call to `wait4()` blocks until the process is stopped, or resumed again after having been stopped.  This is not the same as blocked waiting for input, it means it has been stopped by a signal (`SIGSTOP`).

What you need is `WNOHANG` which stops your `wait4()` from blocking and causes it to return immediately, provbably like this:

```
do 
{
   // All the stuff you want to do
   pid2 = wait4(pid, &status, WNOHANG, &resource_usage);
} while (pid2 == 0);
```

NB I haven't tested the above at all, or even compiled it.

Comment: I tried to change that while to this:
`while (1) 
  {
   dir = opendir(direc); if (dir==NULL) { printf("1"); break; }
   current_memory=get_memory_usage(pid);
            memory_used = max(memory_used,current_memory);
            if (memory_used > MEMORY_LIMIT) 
   {
    res_code = 2;
                kill(pid, SIGKILL); 
   }
        } `

But this loop is break itself. Don't print 1, and breaks.

How I can use `WNOHANG`?

Comment: `WNOHANG` is an option you use in `wait4()`

Comment: I tried `pid2 = wait4(pid, &status, WNOHANG, &resource_usage);`
But when I do output in iteration 198 it write `Name: check.exe
State: R (running)` in iteration 199 it write `Name: main.exe
State: Z (zombie)`
And `VmData:      176 kB
VmStk:       88 kB` in check is standart for all programs which I run from check. I think it is some minimal memory which used by check fork before execute main. how to catch main?

Comment: Is your forked process exiting straight way?

Comment: What means straight way? `pid=fork(); if (pid==0) { exec(); } else { calculate..}` I write my code in post.

Comment: @АлиВелиев Does the child drop out of the while loop at the first attempt.  Try printing the value of pid2 just after the end of the loop.

Comment: No, pid2 printing 0 198 iterations, after he print pid value